# Less in WebStorm

Tags: less, webstorm

Помогите настроить компиляцию less файлов.
Есть куча файлов less. Каждому less файлу соответствует свой css файл.
В webstorm я могу указать как-то пути, чтобы он компилировал в нужный css нужный less?
Пока для одного проекта удается настроить только один файл как на рисунке ниже 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по скриншоту в https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7059?pr=idea, можно использовать шаблоны с wildcards... если что-то не получается, попробуйте задать вопрос автору плагина в https://github.com/acdvorak/intellij-lessc-plugin/issues. а еще вместо LESS CSS Compiler плагина можно попробовать использовать file watchers

Answer (score 2):

Замените `service.less` на `*.less` и будет компилировать всю директорию